# How to connect azure Ad with java web application using certificate?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory, certificate

I have to connect azure ad to my java web application with certificate and without client Secret.
any idea how to do this.

Really appreciate the replies .

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the **If you have a certificate** section in [Instantiating a Confidential Client application](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki/Client-Applications#instantiating-a-confidential-client-application):

```java
String PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID;
String AUTHORITY;
PrivateKey PRIVATE_KEY;  
X509Certificate PUBLIC_KEY;

IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromCertificate(PRIVATE_KEY, PUBLIC_KEY);
ConfidentialClientApplication app = 
    ConfidentialClientApplication
        .builder(PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID, credential)
        .authority(AUTHORITY)
        .build();
```

Also, to [Client Credentials with certificate](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki/Client-Credentials#client-credentials-with-certificate).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any link to sample or dummy project which was for this purpose?

Comment: You're welcome. Here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/tree/dev/src/samples and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code

Comment: I have one question Can we use this for oauth2 client registration?

Comment: My Question is how to deal with Client Registration  in spring Boot Oauth2  because it works with client secret not with certificate and i don't have client secret.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean with client registration?